# Why do my classes not display when my user inputs are valid/unvalid?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm new so sorry if my question is phrased weird.
I am trying to have a certain p tag show up depending if user input is valid or not.

```
    <input id="user-deposit" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="5" max ="500" onkeyup=imposeMinMax(this)>
  
    <div class="prompt">
      <p class="confirm">A</p>
      <p class="error">B</p>
  </div>
```

Here is my css

```
.prompt {
    display: none;
}

input:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}

input:valid {
    border-color: green;
}

input:invalid+p.error {
    display: block;
}

input:valid+p.confirm {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selectors need to be corrected. Have updated the selector a bit here. You have to use  `input:invalid+.prompt>p.error, input:valid+.prompt>p.confirm` to select those elements.

```css
.confirm, .error {
  display: none;
}

input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

input:valid {
  border-color: green;
}

input:invalid+.prompt>p.error,
input:valid+.prompt>p.confirm{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <input id="user-deposit" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="5" max="500">

    <div class="prompt">
      <p class="confirm">A</p>
      <p class="error">B</p>
    </div>
```